# Jersey async client handler never times out after server restarts

Tags: asynchronous, callback, jersey, client, freeze

I have a ReST service I'm connecting to with a Jersey async client. I'm using InvocationCallback to handle responses as callbacks. All is well unless I bounce the server during heavy load from my client service. After a couple of bounces, I find that, beneath the covers, jersey client has registered internal callback handlers for messages that the server will never respond to (because it's been restarted and has lost any indication of an outstanding request).

I would have expected Jersey to (internally) poll its registered async handler list looking for "stale" handlers and cleaning them up with timeout exceptions to the registered invocation callback handlers periodically, but these unanswered handlers never get cleaned up.

What am I doing wrong? This has GOT to be a known issue in Jersey.

I'm building my client like this:

```
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder();
this.client = builder
    .executorService(es)
    .register(JsonProcessingFeature.class)
    .register(LoggingFeature.class)
    .property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_NAME_CLIENT, log.getName())
    .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .withConfig(new ClientConfig().connectorProvider(new JdkConnectorProvider()))
    .build();
```